# XAMPPErrorDomain error 1 for changing MySQL data dirs

Tags: macos, mysql, xampp

I tried to move my mysql data dir from one disk to another, I modified the `datadir` parameter in `my.cnf`, but when XAMPP, and more precisely, MySQL starts, this error is displayed and MySQL doesn't run.

```
Operation could not be completed.  
(XAMPPErrorDomain error 1.)
```

What's the problem here? I correctly specified the new path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your logs: [apache friends - xampp for linux faq >> Error 1](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp-linux.html#error1)

Comment: Thanks, although my error log says nothing about it. Mine is in "Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log"

Comment: Try the mysql logs; they may be in different places. (MySQL docs say they're not available in Console.) See http://serverfault.com/questions/42531/where-is-my-mysql-log-on-os-x

And last resort, check that link above for an email for help with that error.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I realized looking at the logs, that mysqld was not using the datadir from my.cnf but instead was following a symbolic link in '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql' pointing to the old data dir. Changed that and it worked, of course.

Thanks!

Comment: Petruza, any more information or details on what you needed to do to clear this error?

Answer (score 5):

I also have this problem but none of them works, I compared with files one by one on new machine and the old ones finally find the this works for me:

```
sudo chown -R nobody:admin /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/
```

Answer (score 2):

Same error.
Easily resolved on Mac OSX by changing permissions of the Xampp folder in applications to allow read&write access !

Comment: Especially if you just copied back a backup from another machine. Worked for me, too.

Answer (score 1):

I found a tip elsewhere that says to run:

```
> sudo ${XAMPP_HOME}/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

I did, and the result was interesting:

```
> sudo ${XAMPP_HOME}/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
Password:
sudo: /xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server: command not found
```

Thus `${XAMPP_HOME}` is undefined.

So I edited `~/.bash_profile` and added the line:

```
export XAMPP_HOME="/Applications/XAMPP"
```

After restarting Terminal, our command now yields:

```
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.
```

Not sure what to do at this point, but it’s progress.

---

**Update:** I looked in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql` and noticed a .err file (should start with your local computer name, like `johns-macbook-pro.local.err`).  It indicated that my permissions were screwed up: “The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory. File name ./ibdata1”

Setting `/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/var/mysql/` and all its contents to be readable and writable for everyone did the trick. Probably the best solution is to `chown -R mysqld /Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/var/mysql/`.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
ls -la
```

I have this file:

```
/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/share/mysql/mysql.server
```

We can symlink it:

```
rm mysql.server 
ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/mysql/mysql.server mysql.server
```

… and I started MySQL from XAMPP's control panel.

Comment: Reading this is an answer to the question doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by doing the folowing steps.

1. Install XAMPP normally
2. Copy the folders of database from the older location to the folder Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
3. Right click on folder and select Show Information.
4. Add the user ADMIN to the list of users allowed
5. Give permission read-only

This fixed for me when I changed my HD and I needed install all over again.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Look for error files, for example: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/[YOUR_COMPUTER_NAME].err`

An error I sometimes have is:

`Warning: World-writable config file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf' is ignored`

Meaning MySQL will ignore the `my.cnf` file because any-one and their mother can change it (security issue)

Go to the `my.cnf` file, right click > Get Info, Under Sharing & Permissions change Everyone permissions to No Access.